# Instance member '' cannot be used on type '' prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've tried to understand this error before. I hope something is not initialized yet but I can't to figure out how to fix the problem.

This is wrong in `prepareForSegue`:

> Instance member 'choice' cannot be used on type lastVC

I have the following app:

[image: Picture]

The idea is to store the option chosen in each view and send information to the `lastVC` throughout `prepareForSegue`. I have this code but it's not working just it like should.

class VC1:

```
UIViewController {
    var choice : MyChoices?

    @IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        nextOutlet.hidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func redButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        nextOutlet.hidden = false
        colourLabel.text = "Red colour selected"
        choice.color = "Red"
    }

    @IBAction func blueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        nextOutlet.hidden = false
        colourLabel.text = "Blue colour selected"
        choice.color = "Blue"
    }

    @IBAction func greenButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        nextOutlet.hidden = false
        colourLabel.text = "Green colour selected"
        choice.color = "Green"
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let lastVC = segue.destinationViewController as! lastVC
        lastVC.choice = self.choice
    }
}
```

VC2 and VC3 are the same as VC1 (same outlets and buttons)

```
lastVC {
    var choice : MyChoices?

    @IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var styleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sizeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

And the last class to store the strings

```
import UIKit

class MyChoices {
    var colour : String?
    var style : String?
    var size : String?
}
```

Comment: Please highlight properly.

Comment: Also, please copy and past the entire error message you are receiving.

Comment: when it fails? from the first segue?

Comment: Thanks for your time brothers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your segue identifier in `prepareForSegue` method before cast the lastVC. I think your `prepareForSegue` method tries to cast your all VCs to lastVC so it crashes every time. Try to check your segue identifier.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier" {
        let lastVC = segue.destinationViewController as! lastVC
        lastVC.choice = self.choice
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mergenchik!!!! This problem was solved. Now nothing appears in the lastVC (labels are empty). This is the code of my buttons : 

redButton:
 nextOutlet.hidden = false
        
        colourLabel.text = "Red colour selected"
        
        choice?.colour = "Red"

Comment: and viewDidLoad in lastVC looks like this: 

 colourLabel.text = choice?.colour
        styleLabel.text = choice?.style
        sizeLabel.text = choice?.style

Answer (score 0):

try to init a new instance of myChoices and try to pass this to lastVC.choice

And: you should add a convenient init to your myChoices class or make a struct instead

Comment: Thanks for your time bro